# Getting proper json output from restify

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, restify

I have a restify API to print out json output of a MySQL query. Below is the relevant code section;

```
server.get('/echo/:message', function (req, res, next) {
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM hkh.monthly_curves LIMIT 2', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;

        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(rows);
        console.log(jsonString);
        res.send(jsonString);
    });
    connection.end();
    return next();
});
```

The output of `console.log(jsonString);` is a proper json string. Here it is;

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "date_transacted":"1998-05-31T16:00:00.000Z",
      "tbill_1_year":2.6,
      "tbond_2_year":3.15,
      "tbond_5_year":3.94,
      "tbond_10_year":5.3
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "date_transacted":"1998-06-30T16:00:00.000Z",
      "tbill_1_year":3.2,
      "tbond_2_year":3.58,
      "tbond_5_year":4.04,
      "tbond_10_year":5.43
   }
]
```

On the browser, the json output of `res.send(jsonString);` is not properly formatted. It looks like this;

```
"[{\"id\":1,\"date_transacted\":\"1998-05-31T16:00:00.000Z\",\"tbill_1_year\":2.6,\"tbond_2_year\":3.15,\"tbond_5_year\":3.94,\"tbond_10_year\":5.3},{\"id\":2,\"date_transacted\":\"1998-06-30T16:00:00.000Z\",\"tbill_1_year\":3.2,\"tbond_2_year\":3.58,\"tbond_5_year\":4.04,\"tbond_10_year\":5.43}]"
```

How can one make the browser json output be properly formatted? I find it strange that the same variable `jsonString` can look different. Caused by `res.send()`?

EDIT: I found the answer myself. See answer provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to JSON.stringify() the mysql output. `res.send()` will do the json.stringify() itself. In the original code of the question, the extra \ characters was caused by JSON.stringify() the mysql output twice.

```
 server.get('/echo/:message', function (req, res, next) {
        connection.connect();
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM hkh.monthly_curves LIMIT 2', function(err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;

            //var jsonString = JSON.stringify(rows);
            //console.log(jsonString);
            res.send(rows);
        });
        connection.end();
        return next();
    });
```